# Visual Refresh Look for Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I have updated Microsoft Office to the latest version. Currently it is 16.0.16626.20170

I want to get new visual refresh look for office, so I opened the Coming Soon pane from the megaphone icon and switched the toggle of 'Try it now' in one of the applications (for example Word, Powerpoint etc).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-new-look-of-office-a6cdf19a-b2bd-4be1-9515-d74a37aa59bf#ID0EBF=Windows

According to the above article where it says, "If you switch on the visual refresh in Word, Excel, PowerPoint, or OneNote, it will also be available in Outlook."

But I don't get Visual Refresh in Outlook. I have it in all other applications but Outlook. How do I get visual refresh in Outlook?

[Image comparing Outlook and Other Office Application for Visual Refresh Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0IPm.jpg)

Comment: In the top right of outlook, you have a switch "Try the new Outlook" switch that to On. as in your screenshot.

Comment: Try the new outlook is different than the visual refresh look of outlook

Comment: General FYI: When selecting _Try the new Outlook_ you're choosing to replace the Outlook _desktop program_ with the free Outlook _UWP App_ that comes bundled with Windows/is available for free from the Windows Store. You will lose features available on the Desktop version of Outlook - it is not a one-to-one switch _(this is similar to OneNote 2016 versus the free OneNote UWP APP - generally we use the Outlook Desktop program for specific reasons and specific functionality unavailable in the free version of the Outlook UWP App, so it's something to keep in mind)_

Comment: That is correct. My issue is Outlook Desktop version does not have the Visual Refresh applied when I chose Visual Refresh in other Office application. I was wodering if there is a way to force it. As per the documention, if other officce application have visual refresh UI, outlook should also have it

Comment: Looks like Outlook has been applied to the Visual look. Do you mean that there's no changes from before?

Comment: Yes, I don't have visual look in outlook, as you see from the screenshot that I have provided. All other office applications have new look applied.

Comment: Did you restart Outlook to force the Visual look?

Comment: Yes, I restarted both Windows, and Outlook, still nothing. If I start outlook in safe mode "outlook.exe /safe" I get visual look but when I start in normal mode, I get no visual look.  I have disabled all of the add-ins.

Comment: I even uninstalled Microsoft office and reinstalled it, still the same.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the new design is not being pushed out to everyone. It might be due to users running Windows 10 or there might be other reasons.

Regardless you can force most office applications to use the new design.

Open Notepad or your favourite text editor and paste the following into it. Then save the file with a `.reg` extension such as `FluentRefresh.reg`

Then double click the file and click "yes" when it asks if you are sure you want to add the contents.

Then simply close and reopen your Office applications.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentConfigs\ExternalFeatureOverrides]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentConfigs\ExternalFeatureOverrides\access]
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRefresh"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.RibbonTouchOptimization"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRibbonOptionsMenu"="true"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentConfigs\ExternalFeatureOverrides\excel]
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRefresh"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.RibbonTouchOptimization"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRibbonOptionsMenu"="true"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentConfigs\ExternalFeatureOverrides\onenote]
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRefresh"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.RibbonTouchOptimization"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRibbonOptionsMenu"="true"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentConfigs\ExternalFeatureOverrides\outlook]
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRefresh"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.RibbonTouchOptimization"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRibbonOptionsMenu"="true"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentConfigs\ExternalFeatureOverrides\powerpoint]
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRefresh"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.RibbonTouchOptimization"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRibbonOptionsMenu"="true"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentConfigs\ExternalFeatureOverrides\project]
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRefresh"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.RibbonTouchOptimization"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRibbonOptionsMenu"="true"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentConfigs\ExternalFeatureOverrides\powerpoint]
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRefresh"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.RibbonTouchOptimization"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRibbonOptionsMenu"="true"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentConfigs\ExternalFeatureOverrides\project]
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRefresh"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.RibbonTouchOptimization"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRibbonOptionsMenu"="true"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentConfigs\ExternalFeatureOverrides\visio]
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRefresh"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.RibbonTouchOptimization"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRibbonOptionsMenu"="true"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\ExperimentConfigs\ExternalFeatureOverrides\word]
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRefresh"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.RibbonTouchOptimization"="true"
"Microsoft.Office.UXPlatform.FluentSVRibbonOptionsMenu"="true"
```

Comment: I have windows 11 and I already have these registry values set.